# Multithreading / multiprocessing with a python loop

Tags: python, json, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have an script that loops through a range of URLs to pull item location based on returned json data. However, the script takes an 60 minutes to run and 55 minutes of that (per cprofile) is spent waiting for json data to load.

I would like to multithread to run multiple POST requests at a time to speed this up and have initially split up URL ranges into two halves to do this. Where I am getting stuck is how to implement multithreading or asyncio.

Slimmed down code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# i am not recommend to use globals
results = dict()
url = "https://www.website.com/store/ajax/search"
query = "store={}&size=18&query=17360031"

# this is default url opener got from aiohttp documentation
async def open_url(store, loop=None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        async with session.post(url, data={'searchQuery': query.format(store)}) as resp:
            return await resp.json(), store

async def processing(loop=None):
    # U need to use 'global' keyworld if U wan't to write to global variables
    global results
    # one of the simplest ways to parallelize requests, is to init Future, and when data will be ready save it to global
    tasks = [open_url(store, loop=event_loop) for store in range(0, 5)]
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop):
        try:
            data, store = await coro
            results[store] = data['searchResults']['results'][0]['location']['aisle']
        except (IndexError, KeyError):
            continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(processing(loop=event_loop))

# Print Results
for store, data in results.items():
    print(store, data)
```

---

json:

```
    {u'count': 1,
     u'results': [{u'department': {u'name': u'Home', u'storeDeptId': -1},
           u'location': {u'aisle': [A], u'detailed': [A.536]},
           u'score': u'0.507073'}],
     u'totalCount': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use multithreading or multiprocessing, each thread/process will still block until the JSON data is retrieved. This could speed up things a little but it's still not your best choice.

Since you're using requests, try [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) which combines this one with [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). This lets you define a series of HTTP requests that run asynchronously. As a result you'll get a huge speed boost. The usage is very simple: just create a list of requests (using `grequests.get`) and pass it `grequests.map`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - getting this running asynchronously would be ideal. I've looked at the example provided for grequests but they specifically define the list of urls. I'm getting lost on how to apply to the code above? Also, would I use grequests.post instead of grerequests.get?

Answer (score 0):

If u wan't to parallelize requests( i hope u ask for this). This code snippet will help.
There are request opener,and 2000 post requests sent via aiohttp and asyncio.
python3.5 used

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# i am not recommend to use globals
results = dict()
MAX_RETRIES = 5
MATCH_SLEEP_TIME = 3  # i am recommend U to move this variables to other file like constants.py or any else
url = "https://www.website.com/store/ajax/search"
query = "store={}&size=18&query=44159"

# this is default url opener got from aiohttp documentation
async def open_url(store, semaphore, loop=None):
    for _ in range(MAX_RETRIES):
        with await semarhore:
            try:
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
                    async with session.post(url, data={'searchQuery': query.format(store)}) as resp:
                        return await resp.json(), store
            except ConnectionResetError:
                # u can handle more exceptions here, and sleep if they are raised
                await asyncio.sleep(MATCH_SLEEP_TIME, loop=loop)
                continue
    return None

async def processing(semaphore, loop=None):
    # U need to use 'global' keyworld if U wan't to write to global     variables
    global results
    # one of the simplest ways to parallelize requests, is to init     Future, and when data will be ready save it to global
    tasks = [open_url(store, semaphore, loop=event_loop) for store in range(0,     2000)]
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop):
        try:
            response = await coro
            if response is None:
                continue
            data, store = response
            results[store] = data['searchResults']['results'][0]['location']['aisle']
        except (IndexError, KeyError):
            continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(50, loop=event_loop)  # count of concurrent requests
    event_loop.run_until_complete(processing(semaphore, loop=event_loop))
```

Comment: I'm getting "NameError: name 'store' is not defined" when I try to run. I made some updates to the original post, - and am not sure where the "query = "store={}&size=18&query=44159"
" and "data = json.loads(r.json()'searchResults'])['results'][0]" are handled in your revisions. Thanks!

Comment: @MiaElla Hey, update my answer, but i get html from response, not json, are u sure, the url the correct? I recommend u to except **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError** to avoid json decode errors. Also i recommend u to use setdefault nor defaultdict

Comment: You are correct, website name has been corrected for this test. I've corrected but still getting a host of errors: File "C:/Users...test.py", line 34, in <module>
    event_loop.run_until_complete(processing(loop=event_loop))
 line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
 line 27, in processing
    results.setdefault(store, []).append(data['searchResults']['results'][0]['location']['aisle'])

Comment: @MiaElla Update my answer. U send one request for each store, setdefault is useless here. Can u show full traceback please?

Comment: @Bodgan - Looks like this works smaller ranges. If I up the search range into the hundreds I get "Task was destroyed but it is pending!". Is there a time function I should add to slow down query?

Comment: @MiaElla U limit number of concurrent requests via [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore)

Comment: Thanks - I tried running with the range from 0-100 and got the errors noted in the trackback above. It worked prior to the semaphore additions on that range - maybe my eyes just need a little rest (I did fix the one spelling error for semaphore in line 11, but still no luck).

Comment: @MiaElla Hey, may be exception raised cause i don't pass loop to Semaphore. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! The code works, but I believe it quickly overloads the host (even with limiting concurrent requests via the semaphore). Is there a way to add a explicit time delay/sleep to the semaphore or loops to limit how many concurrent requests are sent per X seconds?

"ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: @MiaElla Updated sleep. But i still recommend u decrease semaphore value, cause sleep in this code will just block request and won't give expected result, but the semaphore will. Added few retries in request sending, if exception raised while request processing, sleep will be called, and than continue processing. Answer updated. –

Comment: Bohdan Biloshytskiy - Can you help me with printing the json data from a result like this page outputs? https://search.mobile.walmart.com/v1/products-by-code/UPC/037000754213?storeId=3

I'm trying to use the above approach with this new link but am having trouble implementing given the http request goes straight to json data.